# NodeJS: Share mongoose connection between scripts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I've got a `.js` file which on the beginning inits a MongoDB connection (via mongoose), then does some logic and then executes another script which also requires mongoose connection. 
The **problem** is that the *child* script doesn't see the connection created by its parent and therefore inits a new one.

A code snippet of the parent script:

```
initDBConnection();
doProcessing();
child_process.execSync('npm run migrations'); // here the child script gets executed
doAnotherProcessing();
```

So the question is whether it is somehow possible to *share* mongoose connection created by the parent so the child script would not be forced to init a new connection.

Note: The **child** script is an npm library for migrations

EDIT
The only problem I face is that during the lifetime of the parent script, a connection to the database is created more than single time.

**First time** before the `child_process.execSync('npm run migrations');` gets run

**Second time** inside the `migrations` script

The goal is to use the db connection created before the child process gets executed.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you think that sharing the mongodb connection is going to solve the problem?

Comment: @ChrisEdgington I've updated the description

Comment: Well - you just added more details about how you're trying to solve a problem. What is the actual problem? The "I need to share a single connection" is a symptom of your attempt to solve a problem - what is that problem?

Comment: Also - why does it matter if there are more db connections? This is a normal part of the mongodb lifecycle.

Comment: @ChrisEdgington the library for migrations picks up migration definitions and executes `up()` methods inside every migration file. 
For example: let's say I have 20 migration files and an empty database. When the `migrate` command is run, it will pick file by file, will init mongo connection for every one of them. 
I will end up with 20 connections which I'd like to eliminate but they're not causing any problems - it's just a matter of migrations effectivity/performance
The library used: https://www.npmjs.com/package/migrate

Comment: I honestly would expect performance to be better with the multiple connections vs a single connection. And definitely looking at the library link you provided, there is no way to share the DB connection you are creating in your parent script with the execution of migrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mongodb connection is a runtime object created within the mongodb node driver of the running node process. You cannot pass this object to another launch of node.

Comment: Yep you're right. I basically expected this answer but I hoped that maybe there's a trick for it.

Comment: @user2151486 Would you mind giving the answer an upvote ... since you agree that it is correct :)